# Deserialize List of base classes to derived ones using Gson

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm building and **Android app**, which communicates with a C# server using JSON.

I have a data class to be serialized (actually, to deserialize the received data into), which contains a List field of derived classes, but storing them as the base class of them:

```
public class ToSerializeClass{
    @SerializedName("TestString")
    private String testString = "TestStringValue";

    @SerializedName("DerivedClasses")
    private List<BaseClass> derivedClasses;

    public List<BaseClass> getDerivedClasses() {
        return derivedClasses;
    }

    public ToSerializeClass(List<BaseClass> derivedClasses){
        this.derivedClasses= derivedClasses;
    }
}
```

For example, from C# side if I'm receiving the following ToSerializeClass instance, called *serializeClass*:

```
List<BaseClass> derivedClasses = new ArrayList<>();
derivedClasses.add(new DerivedClassA());
derivedClasses.add(new DerivedClassB());
ToSerializeClass serializeClass = new ToSerializeClass(derivedClasses);
```

The JSON String would be:

```
{"__type":"ToSerializeClass","DerivedClasses":[{"__type":"DerivedA","FieldA":"This is a derived class."},{"__type":"DerivedB","FieldB":"This is ANOTHER derived class.", "IntValue":10}],"TestString":"TestStringValue"}
```

The *"__type":"SimpleClassName"* field of the JSON String shows the serialized class's simple name. Those are added by the C# side's serializer.
I can make those fields to disappear, if necessary, but it was the solution of this same problem at C# side.
Without the types it would look like this:

```
{"DerivedClasses":[{"FieldA":"This is a derived class."},{"FieldB":"This is ANOTHER derived class.", "IntValue":10}],"TestString":"TestStringValue"}
```

**The problem** is, when I try to **deserialize** the JSON String to an instance of the *ToSerializeClass* class:

```
Gson serializer = new Gson();
ToSerializeClass deserialized = serializer.fromJson(jsonString, ToSerializeClass.class);
```

I have the *deserialized* class which is a *ToSerializeClass* instance, but the *derivedClasses* List is a collection of base classes instead of derived ones, and all of the derived information are lost.

How can I deserialize the String to a *ToSerializeClass* instance to have a List of derived classes?

I have full control over the source code, so I'm able to modify my data classes, to use different collection(s) if necessary, to create some wrappers, modify JSON String, but I'd like to solve it using Gson if possible and can be done without too much overhead.

Thanks!

**Edit:** for example *DerivedClassA* and *DerivedClassB*:

```
public class DerivedClassA extends BaseClass{
    @SerializedName("FieldA")
    private String fieldA = "This is a derived class.";

    ...

    public DerivedClassA(){
        super();
    }
}

public class DerivedClassB extends BaseClass{
    @SerializedName("FieldB")
    private String fieldB = "This is ANOTHER derived class.";

    @SerializedName("IntValue")
    private int intValue = 10;
    ...

    public DerivedClassB(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a fast solution, which is close to the one I was looking for (I'm not a Java guy, so I'm sorry if it hurts your brain, feel free to comment advices).

Data classes:

```
public class BaseClass {
    @SerializedName("Method")
    private String method;

    public void setMethod(String method){
        this.method = method;
    }

    public String getMethod(){
        return method;
    }

    public BaseClass(String method){
        this.method = method;
    }
}

public class DerivedClassA extends BaseClass{
    @SerializedName("FieldA")
    private String fieldA = "This is a derived class.";

    public DerivedClassA(){
        super("ClassA");
    }
}

public class DerivedClassB extends BaseClass{
    @SerializedName("FieldB")
    private String fieldB = "This is ANOTHER derived class.";

    @SerializedName("IntValue")
    private int intValue = 10;

    public DerivedClassB(){
        super("ClassB");
    }
}

public class ToSerializeClass{
    @SerializedName("TestString")
    private String testString = "TestStringValue";

    @SerializedName("DerivedClasses")
    private List<BaseClass> derivedClasses;

    public ToSerializeClass(List<BaseClass> derivedClasses){
        this.derivedClasses= derivedClasses;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:** The *ClassDeserializerAdapter* implementation:

```
public class ClassDeserializerAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<BaseClass>
{
    private String typeName;
    private Gson gson;
    private Map<String, Class<? extends BaseClass>> classTypeRegistry;

    ClassDeserializerAdapter(String typeName)
    {
        this.typeName = typeName;
        gson = new Gson();
        classTypeRegistry = new HashMap<>();
    }

    void registerClassType(String classTypeName, Class<? extends BaseClass> classType)
    {
        // registering Types to Strings
        classTypeRegistry.put(classTypeName, classType);
    }

    @Override
    public BaseClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) 
        throws JsonParseException
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement typeElement = jsonObject.get(typeName);
        String method = typeElement.getAsString();
        Class<? extends BaseClass> classType = classTypeRegistry.get(method);
        BaseClass result = gson.fromJson(json, classType);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works for me just fine, without even having temporary classes etc.

*Note: with reflection, it could automatically register every classes which are inherited from BaseClass, and you won't even have to deal with the register process.*

**EXAMPLE:** The *main()* method's body is:

```
// **SERIALIZATION PART** (nothing special, simple Gson serialization)
// Creating a list to pass as parameter to the container class
List<BaseClass> derivedClasses = new ArrayList<>();
derivedClasses.add(new DerivedClassA());
derivedClasses.add(new DerivedClassB());
// Creating the container class to be serialized
ToSerializeClass serializeClass = new ToSerializeClass(derivedClasses);

Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(serializeClass);
// json = {"TestString":"TestStringValue","DerivedClasses":[{"FieldA":"This is a derived class.","Method":"ClassA"},{"FieldB":"This is ANOTHER derived class.","IntValue":10,"Method":"ClassB"}]}


// **DESERIALIZATION PART** (with custom deserializer)
// creating the custom deserializer, which will find the derived class' type as the class' "Method" field value. With that value, it can resolve the type.. see below
ClassDeserializerAdapter deserializer = new ClassDeserializerAdapter("Method");
// registering each Type into the Deserializer's HashMap (key-value pair), where the key (String) must be carried by the object (you can find it in the BaseClass, called "Method")
deserializer.registerClassType("ClassA", DerivedClassA.class);
deserializer.registerClassType("ClassB", DerivedClassB.class);
Gson gsonB = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(BaseClass.class, deserializer).create();

// deserializing
ToSerializeClass deserialized = gsonB.fromJson(json, ToSerializeClass.class); // CORRECT!
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this classes

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class DerivedClass {

    @SerializedName("__type")
    private String __type;

    @SerializedName("FieldA")
    private String fieldA;

    @SerializedName("FieldB")
    private String fieldB;

    public String get__type() {
        return __type;
    }

    public void set__type(String __type) {
        this.__type = __type;
    }

    public String getFieldA() {
        return fieldA;
    }

    public void setFieldA(String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    public String getFieldB() {
        return fieldB;
    }

    public void setFieldB(String fieldB) {
        this.fieldB = fieldB;
    }
}
```

Make a `Response.java` who will get the `JSON` data

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

    @SerializedName("__type")
    private String __type;

    @SerializedName("DerivedClasses")
    private ArrayList<DerivedClass> derivedClasses;

    @SerializedName("TestString")
    private String testString;

    public String get__type() {
        return __type;
    }

    public void set__type(String __type) {
        this.__type = __type;
    }

    public ArrayList<DerivedClass> getDerivedClasses() {
        return derivedClasses;
    }

    public void setDerivedClasses(ArrayList<DerivedClass> derivedClasses) {
        this.derivedClasses = derivedClasses;
    }

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }
}
```

now all you have to do is use this line and you will get your data

```
    Response response = (new Gson()).fromJson("your_JSON", Response.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution looks like I would have to store all of the derived classes' properties / fields into one - Response - class. Since there are a lot of different derived classes, it would be a huge "data class" (sometimes with field name equivalence). I would prefer the way - if possible - to deserialize/reflect the data to the original derived classes. (I know, I could create the derived classes after getting the necessary values from the response class, but.. that's just not nice.) :) Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong about your example.

Comment: @KAI, you certainly remind me of BayBlade's. your derived class would be nested as  in the **json** list so you don't have to worry about the Respose class won't increase in size,. About derived classes would, actually can be subclaased as you try to create Model classes for them, pretty much convenient if you know the structure of the **JSON** which you get from the server